# Adding all the 1's in a row?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum, row

I have a very large matrix(around 4000000x2) , and it has 1s sprinkled throughout the matrix. What I want to do is that I just want to add up all the 1s in one row.

For example, if I have a matrix like this:

```
A = [0 0 4 1 0 0 1
     1 0 5 0 7 0 1 
     5 6 0 8 1 0 6 
     0 9 5 1 0 0 0]
```

Is there a way of summing up all of the 1's a row? For example, here it would be:

```
sum = [2
       2
       1
       1]
```

I know that if you want to add up the whole row, you can use `sum(A,2)`. But is there a way in matlab to add up all of a specific number? I'm new to matlab and I would greatly appreciate any help, thank you!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generate an array that has a 1 everywhere `A` has a 1, and 0 everywhere else:

```
>> A == 1
ans =
     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

Then you can just use `sum`:

```
sum(A == 1, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea that sum could be used that way.

Comment: @ocean800, well, `sum` actually does exactly the same thing as you think. The trick is to use the [comparison operator `==`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eq.html). Consider accepting my answer.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks! I will accept your answer... in about 6 minutes.